# iOS: How to make a custom swipe-to-delete function in UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to do wipe-to-delete the same as the iOS system's,but I just want to self-define this.

NOT USE THIS:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
        commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle 
         forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

By the way,I want the same effect with the system's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your own Sliding cell which slide view of cell. 
Else explore custom controls in cocoacontrols.com
here is one of them https://github.com/ask-fm/AFMSlidingCell